# Are questions about heroku on or off topic?

Tags: discussion

I can come up with reasons why and why not. Heroku is a Salesforce owned company that does have some integration with Salesforce, but it is still a separate platform.

Comment: Heroku is a Salesforce company and is sold as a key part of the Salesforce Platform story. Heroku questions should be allowed here.

Answer (score 9):

I guess it depends.  If the questions are integration with Salesforce related questions like the one recently posted on [Overcoming Database.com latency on Heroku](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/332/overcoming-database-com-latency) then I think they are totally appropriate.  If the question has nothing to do with Salesforce, for example, something like "How do I get my config file set up correctly", I'd say that doesn't belong.  That type of question is on par with asking a question like "How do I set up the applicationContext file in my Java Spring web app" and is not directly related to Salesforce.

For me, the key is that the question must contain some sort of integration with Salesforce.

Comment: You couldn't have summed up my thought any better. Questions about integrations are fine, this includes not just Heroku but php .net anything. But a straight up Heroku question belongs elsewhere

Comment: Yep +1 from me, right on the money. If it's an integration piece it definitely fits, but if we're talking about a ruby problem for a standalone web app then it should be on Stackoverflow.

Comment: I agree with wuputah and Matt Lacey. If it's a programming question, users should definitely go to Stack Overflow. However, Heroku is a Salesforce product and questions about the service absolutely belong here (just like Quip: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quip )

Comment: Someone needs to define Salesforce here.  If it's by definition the stuff you can buy from Salesforce it's appropriate - if there's some other definition that needs to be clear somewhere

Answer (score 7):

Heroku is a Salesforce product and is part of App Cloud. Any product-related question about Heroku is welcome here. Programming specific questions that are unrelated to Heroku should be asked on Stack Overflow.